# calling function with alias declared in other module in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, import

This is the content of `v4.js` file inside `uuid` folder in Angular `node_modules`:

```
var rng = require('./lib/rng');
var bytesToUuid = require('./lib/bytesToUuid');

function v4(options, buf, offset) {
  var i = buf && offset || 0;

  if (typeof(options) == 'string') {
    buf = options == 'binary' ? new Array(16) : null;
    options = null;
  }
  options = options || {};

  var rnds = options.random || (options.rng || rng)();

  // Per 4.4, set bits for version and `clock_seq_hi_and_reserved`
  rnds[6] = (rnds[6] & 0x0f) | 0x40;
  rnds[8] = (rnds[8] & 0x3f) | 0x80;

  // Copy bytes to buffer, if provided
  if (buf) {
    for (var ii = 0; ii < 16; ++ii) {
      buf[i + ii] = rnds[ii];
    }
  }

  return buf || bytesToUuid(rnds);
}

module.exports = v4;
```

I am using this statement to import the function:

```
import { v4 as uuid } from 'uuid';
```

To my surprise, there are 2 ways of calling v4 function:

I can use:

```
uuid.v4();
```

or simply

```
uuid();
```

How come `uuid()` still calls v4 function?

Comment: You can call it both ways because the alias technically *is* function `v4`, whilst at the same time the alias has a function reference to all the modules export functions as well.

Comment: Well if it's just that, it looks like a global function (the file isn't an anonymous function). Maybe that explains it ? To be sure, try calling the v4 function in your Chrome console, if it pops, then it's global.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behaviour isn't specific to TypeScript. This happens because of [the way the export works](https://github.com/kelektiv/node-uuid/blob/v3.1.0/index.js#L4-L8) in this package.

Since default and `*` exports aren't distinguished in CommonJS modules, named exports are commonly exported as properties of `module.exports`. `v4` is currently a default export, and this will possibly change in future package versions:

```
const uuid = require('uuid');
uuid === uuid.v4;
```

Comment: Thanks for stopping by! What exactly is * export?   I see that I have poor knowledge about how this packages work. For example I have no idea what index.js in doing here. What exactly should I google to educate myself?

Comment: See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import for *. `*` and `default` are separate things in ES6 modules but same thing in CommonJS modules. You can check more on CJS modules here https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/modules.html , or possibly one of 'CommonJS vs ES6' articles. Hope this answers your question. `v4` is just a method on itself, so it could be used `v4.v4.v4()` as well.